# Publishing mosiac datasets for ArcReader?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, imagery, arcreader

Has anyone had luck with publishing their own imagery into ArcReader 10.2 in a mosaic dataset?

I have had success publishing the my own imagery in tiles but not in a mosaic form.

Does anyone have any suggestions or tips?

Answer (score 1):

I just copied the original image tiles onto the computer running arcreader, then created an unmanaged image catalog pointing at the image tiles.

The catalog works fine in ArcReader.